# Dropping index concurrently PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql

`DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY` first appeared in PSQL 9.2, but my server runs 9.1. Unfortunately that operation locks my app for an unpredictable amount of time, that's a very sad fact when doing it on production.

Is there a way to drop an index concurrently?

Comment: You said it yourself: you need to 9.2 (or possibly upgrade to 9.3 right away).

Comment: Maybe a hack/workaround exists...

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no simple workaround - otherwise it's rather less likely that `DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY` would've been added in 9.2.

However, you *can* kill all sessions to force the `drop` to occur promptly.

What you want to avoid is the drop waiting on a partially acquired exclusive lock that prevents other transactions from proceeding, but doesn't let it proceed either, while it waits for other transactions to finish and release their share locks. The best way to ensure that happens is to kill all concurrent sessions.

So, in one session:

```
DROP INDEX my_index;
```

In another session, as a superuser, terminate all other sessions using the following *untested* query, which you'll need to adapt appropriately and test before use:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE procpid <> (
    SELECT pid 
    FROM pg_stat_activity 
    WHERE query = 'DROP INDEX my_index;')
  AND
    procpid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Your well-written and well-tested application will immediately reconnect and retry its queries without bothering the user or getting upset, because it knows that transient errors are something it has to cope with so it runs all its database access in retry loops. If it isn't well written then you'll discover that with a flood of error user-visible messages. If it's really not well written you'll have to restart it before it gets its head together, but it's rare to see apps that are quite that broken.

This is a heavy handed approach. You can be rather softer about it by joining against `pg_locks` and only terminating sessions that actually hold a lock on the relation you're interested in or the index you wish to modify. You get to enjoy writing that query, because my interest in working around limitations of older database versions is limited.